# How to loop through string array and add each element to object array

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, loops, object

Im trying to loop through a string array named `string[] splitWords`. The array is in the following format:

```
 // Write your main here
    Write("Enter a number between 1 & 10: ");
    int input = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());

    Random ranNumberGenerator = new Random();
    int randomNumber;
    randomNumber = ranNumberGenerator.Next(1, 11);

    if (input == randomNumber)
    {
        WriteLine("correct");
    }
    else if (input < randomNumber)
    {
        WriteLine("too low");
    }
    else
    {
        WriteLine("too high");
    }
```

Im currently trying to loop through the array which has each element split up individually and assign it to an object array. For example,  need to be in their own object array element and so on (every 3 elements). And so in total, there will be 5 elements in the object array. Currently my code is not working, or giving me any errors.

```
 // Write your main here
        Write("Enter a number between 1 & 10: ");
        int input = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());

        Random ranNumberGenerator = new Random();
        int randomNumber;
        randomNumber = ranNumberGenerator.Next(1, 11);

        if (input == randomNumber)
        {
            WriteLine("correct");
        }
        else if (input < randomNumber)
        {
            WriteLine("too low");
        }
        else
        {
            WriteLine("too high");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is close, all you need to do is remove the `if` block

instead of:

```
stationNames[stationCounter] = new Station(splitWords[i], splitWords[i + 1], splitWords[i + 2]);
if (stationCounter % 3 == 0)
{
    stationCounter++;
}
```

You just need:

```
stationNames[stationCounter] = new Station(splitWords[i], splitWords[i + 1], splitWords[i + 2]);
stationCounter++;
```

Because each iteration of the loop moves 3 increments so you just need to increment the while counter each time.

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ will make this task very easy:

```
Station[] stationNames = splitWords
  .Select(word => word.Split(' '))
  .Select(a => new Station(a[0], a[1], a[2]))
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work when i try to add it? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @nextgenben99 In what way it doesn't work? What errors does it generate?

Comment: It says System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Comment: @nextgenben99 - Then you have a line that doesn't have three items on it. What does your real data look like?

Comment: There is a possibility that LINQ is out of scope (too advanced) for a (possible) homework assignment